# Ubuntu freezes while booting

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Fresh install of Ubuntu is consistently freezing while booting.  Sometimes in logs in and sometimes it doesn't.  What seems to be the issue?  Thanks

PS.  I have a picture but I'm not able to upload it

Comment: You should add more information to your question so they can help you: computer model, what ubuntu you put, what exactly happens, etc.
You can take a tour to see how to ask a question. Then surely someone will help you.
[how to ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add link to uploaded image on some 3rd party service like imgur.com . BTW askubuntu make same upload automatically in own internal editor.